# Proof that $\sum_i \lvert \alpha_i\rvert \leq |x|$, where $|x|$ is the norm

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

On another post a user asked for a proof that if a map is linear then it is continuous.  ["Every linear mapping on a finite dimensional space is continuous"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112985/every-linear-mapping-on-a-finite-dimensional-space-is-continuous/833995#833995)

I have pasted an image of the answer which I am having trouble understanding.  In the last line he replaces  $\sum_i \lvert \alpha_i\rvert$ with $|x|$, so it must either be equal or less for the conclusion to follow.

**Question**
Why is this sum of scalars equal or less than the norm?

Thanks

---

[image]

Comment: There was a mistake in that proof and it was pointed out in the comments. It is not true that $\sum |\alpha_i| \leq ||x||$ for any norm when $x=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$. For example this is not true for the usual norm on $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Comment: Could we fix it by writing $\sum |\alpha_i| \leq q||x||$, for some $q \in \mathbb{R}$ and letting $\delta =\dfrac{\epsilon}{mq}$

Comment: Yes, that is how you can fix that proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Norms on finite-dimensional spaces are equivalent. You can check that $||x||_0 := \sum_i |\alpha_i|$ defines a norm on $X$ (in fixing that basis for $X$). Since the given norm $||\cdot||$ is another norm on $X$, a finite-dimensional space, it then follows that $||\cdot||_0$ and $||\cdot||$ are equivalent, i.e. there exists some constant $C>0$ such that $||\cdot||_0 \leq C ||\cdot||$. Adjusting your $\delta$ to be instead $\varepsilon / (CM)$ gets what you want

You can read something such as [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57686/understanding-of-the-theorem-that-all-norms-are-equivalent-in-finite-dimensional%22this%20post%22) to learn more about this property of norm equivalence in finite-dimensional spaces

Comment: So  you're letting each $\alpha_i$ in $\sum_i |\alpha_i|$  represent basis vectors that span $X$?

Comment: No I am using the original post's notation (e.g. in the attached picture), where the $\alpha_i$ are the coordinates of $x \in X$ relative to the fixed basis $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ of $X$, i.e. $x = \sum_i \alpha_i e_i$ or $x = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$.

Comment: ah, I missed that.  Thanks!  Also by the $\delta$ $\epsilon$ definition to show continuity wouldn't we have to show $|x-a|< \delta$ gives $|T(x)-T(a)| < \epsilon$?  But in their proof they just show $|x|< \delta$ implies $|T(x)|< \epsilon$.  Does the $|x-a|$ case follow trivially from proving the $|x|$ case?  Because showing $|x|$ shows continuity at $0$, or am I missing something.  Thanks again.

Comment: no problem ^_^. Actually there is an important property of continuity of linear maps used there: Any linear map $T$ between normed spaces is continuous if and only if it is continuous at $0$ (e.g. see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270819/a-linear-map-continuous-at-zero-is-bounded)). So showing that $||x||<\delta$ implies $||Tx||<\varepsilon$ is showing continuity at $0$, which as noted is sufficient for continuity everywhere (e.g. that $||x-a||<\delta$ implies $||Tx-Ta||<\varepsilon$).